# Killing Tmux window from outside tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

On a Linux machine, I run Tmux session with 3 windows. I connect to this Linux machine using ssh. A process running in one window is spewing lot of logs, pretty much not letting me do anything else (can't switch windows or even kill that window). Is there a way I can kill this window from the shell (by opening another ssh connection to this box)? I do not want to kill the process. Just the window.

Comment: Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. This question may be appropriate on other SE sites such as [unix.se]. Check their help first to see if the question belongs there and if so you can click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" to request migration there.

Comment: I think it is ok because this question about programming tool `software tools commonly used by programmers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `man tmux` there is command called `kill-window`

> kill-window [-a] [-t target-window]
>                      (alias: killw)
>
> Kill the current window or the window at target-window, removing it
>   from any sessions to which it is linked.  The -a option kills all but
>   the window given with -t.

So if you know window name or index you can press `Prefix+:` to call command mode and than type

```
kill-window -t window_name
```

Or from outside of tmux

```
tmux kill-window -t session_name:window_name
```